# SQL array display in rows without SQL query

Tags: php

I am trying to test a few scripts that I would normally get from an SQL database but for testing offline I am just creating an array.

Here is what I have right now;

```
$result = array
(
    array("name"=>"Toby", "q1"=>"1"),
    array("name"=>"Phelps", "q1"=>"1"),
    array("name"=>"Davies", "q1"=>"1"),
    array("name"=>"Keith", "q1"=>"1"),
);

$resultnum = count($result);
echo "<b>Question 1</b> <br/><br/>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $answer = $row['q1'];

        $q1answer = 1;

        if($answer == $q1answer) {
            echo $name . " got this right! <br/>";
        } else {
            echo $name . " got this wrong! <br/>";
        }

    }
}
```

How can I get this to work the same as though it was getting the array from an SQL query instead of just my array, for some reason I can't find a way to get this to run.

Comment: You're going to have to create a class that mimics the mysqli_result object, complete with the functions you'll be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the earlier answer, I propose a class. Here I would actually name the class, and pass the data to the constructor. The iteration over the array can be done with the `current` and `next` methods:

```
class ResultSet {
    private $array = [];
    public $num_rows = 0;
    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->array = $data;
        $this->num_rows = count($this->array);
    }
    public function fetch_assoc() {
        $val = current($this->array);
        next($this->array);
        return $val;
    }
}
```

Until there it would be fixed. You would play with the data in the following:

```
$result = new ResultSet([
        ["name"=>"Toby",   "q1"=>"1"],
        ["name"=>"Phelps", "q1"=>"1"],
        ["name"=>"Davies", "q1"=>"1"],
        ["name"=>"Keith",  "q1"=>"1"],
    ]);
```

I did not implement support  for `count($result)` as I don't think that is supported on real mysqli result sets either. You get the count via `->num_rows` (like you also do).

Comment: Good point about countable. I overlooked that that shouldn't actually exist.

Comment: That's great, simple enough to follow and works fine with my above script. The count($results) was just left over from something I was trying out so that's not important. Thanks for the quick help! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the array in an [anonymous class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php). Single uses like this are a main reason they exist.

```
$result = new class {
    private $data = array
    (
        array("name"=>"Toby", "q1"=>"1"),
        array("name"=>"Phelps", "q1"=>"1"),
        array("name"=>"Davies", "q1"=>"1"),
        array("name"=>"Keith", "q1"=>"1"),
    );
    private $data_index = 0;
    public $num_rows;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->num_rows = count($this->data);
    }

    public function fetch_assoc() {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->data_index])) {
            $index = $this->data_index++;
            return  $this->data[$index];
        }
    }
};
```